# queires and advanced operations in influxdb

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

Recently started working on influxDB, can't find how to add new measurements or make a table of data from separate measurements, like in SQL we have to join table or so.

The `influxdb` docs aren't that clear. I'm currently using the terminal for everything and wouldn't mind switching to python but most of it is about HTTP post schemes in the docs, is there any other alternative?

I would prefer influxDB in python if the community support is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The InfluxDB query language does not support joins across measurements.

It instead needs to be done client side after querying data. Querying, without join, data from multiple measurements *can* be done with one query.